# Xcode 6.3.2 - App installation failed

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Since yesterday, I try to compile my application on my iPhone, but I have this error message:

> App installation failed
>
> An unknown error has occurred.

[image]

That worked until now.
I checked the certificates, it seems to be good.

Have you already met this problem?

Thanks

**PS :** That works on simulators but not on external devices (iPhone / iPad).

**Edit :** It's now fix, thanks.

Go to Xcode Preferences -> Click on Accounts -> Select my AppleID -> Click on View Details -> Click on refresh icon.

And force clean my project.

It works well!

Comment: give it a try --->>> quite Xcode and open it again, now run on device

Comment: Go to Xcode prefrences --> click on Accounts --> Select your Account --> View Details --> click on refresh icon. Now select your proper Profiles and hit run on device.

Comment: This can have a lot of reasons: Do you use external librarys or is no more disk space left on the iOS device?

Comment: Is there any special character in your app name? If you have, try to remove. Or if you're using cocoa pods, please try "pod update". Let me know if it's works...

Comment: sometimes it's happen when you don't have any empty space on device too Paul Jarysta.

Comment: In fact, I have a hypothesis. As Apple has changed its rules for the developer license (including mac license), the signing identities were not up to date ans when I reloaded them, the signing identities Mac appeared and everything worked. :-)

Answer (score 23):

this happens with me also sometimes. all certificates are fine. provisioning profiles are ok. but still error occurs. try this trick:

```
Product>Clean>force quit Xcode>reopen Xcode>clean>select device>run
```

if stil dont work check your code signing, your provisioning profile must contain same code signing that you have in your keychain.
if still doesnt work. then delete your provisioning profile and create new one,with same code signing identities.

Comment: This saved me several hours. Thank you

Comment: Product>Clean was enough for me.

Comment: I had more than 2 days without test on my device, this just works. :D Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Goto product -> clean

quit xcode

then open again

again product -> clean

then run the app

it will work

thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Pod then make the framework of pod optional

Answer (score 1):

Delete the application from device manually and Run xcode application again. It will work.

Comment: Welcome anytime @LinkonSid

Answer (score 1):

So I had the same issue just now. This was due to adding a new pod to my project.

What worked for me was deleting the existing app on the phone and hitting "clean" (Product -> Clean || shift + cmd + k) on Xcode.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

This keeps happening to me and it's because somehow my Apple ID gets signed out, or corrupted.

## Steps to fix:

1. In the menu, go to `Xcode > Preferences > Accounts`
2. Select "Apple ID" on the left
3. On the right, sign in again
4. Go to general settings and make sure you have the proper *Team* selected
5. In the menu, `Product > Clean`

That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes i'm having this issue. The reasons can be different, sometimes it can be prov. profiles. Last time i face this issue all was correct, cleaning target and restarting xcode didn't help. i just force switch off iphone and issue was resolved.
So switich off iphone can be another solution.

xCode 7.3, iOS 7.2, iphone 4s.